# Shove knowing about an object but unable to retrieve it

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

After a lot of playing around I found a workaround for some weird behaviour but would like to understand what's going on. Sorry if I am missing elementary stuff but I am pretty inexperienced in python.

So...

I am storing an object in Shove in one script and retrieving in another one - all works fine if I use my workaround

**`shove_repro_class.y`**

```
 class MyClass():
        def __init__(self, name ):
            self.name = name
            self.othername = "%s" % name    ## <=== workaround for 
                                            ## <=== self.othername = name
        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Object "%s"' % self.name
```

**`shove_repro.py` (this is the first script to run)**

```
from shove import Shove
from shove_repro_class import MyClass

location = 'file://test'
#   location = 'sqlite:///test.db'  # this won't work any better
data = Shove(location)
data['somename'] = MyClass('somename')

data.close()
```

**`shove_repro2.py` (this is the second script to run)**

```
from shove import Shove
from shove_repro_class import MyClass

location = 'file://test'
#   location = 'sqlite:///test.db'  ## same remark as before

data = Shove(location)
print data.keys()            # prints [ 'somename' ]
print data[data.keys()[0]]   # throws an exception in some cases (see 1. below) !
```

**Couple of questions:**

1. If I replace `self.othername = "%s" % name` by `self.othername = name` then I won't be able to retrieve the data from Shove. This workaround took me a long while to figure out and so I feel there's something fishy going out that I need to find out about otherwise I'm going to be surprised very often. I was thinking that maybe there's a deep/shallow copy issue here but given that I would think strings are immutable there should be no other possible copy than deep - right?
2. Irrespective of my workaround, how's it possible that `data.keys()` has my `'somename'` key but yet `data['somename']` does not work?
3. Seems like `shove_repro2.py` still works if `MyClass` is not explicitly imported. Does this mean that the shove object stores the class definition?

Thx so much!

Comment: With regards to 1: without your workaround (which can get replaced by the simpler `name[:]` btw) both `self.name` and `self.othername` contain the exact same instance.

Comment: #2: the `__getitem__` in `FileBase` in `base.py` uses a `try/except` pair which catches any exception and reraises it as a KeyError.  The underlying exception is really a `BadPickleGet: 5` error.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe thx for the name[:] thingy but I don't get why they would have the same instance, it's not like I did `self.name = self.othername = name`

Comment: @DSM - I suspected it's a pickling issue - that's why I added pickle as keyword ;-) but I still don't get the reason for it

Comment: @cozycoding: Unlike some other languages when you do `a = b` in Python you don't create a copy. All that happens is that you make `a` act as another alias for the instance `b` contains.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe: but if I do `a=b="something"; b="somethingelse";a` it returns `"something"` so clearly `a` and `b` are not refering to the same instance?

Comment: @cozycoding: `a = b = "something"` is the same as: `t = "something"; a = t; b = t;`. I just use the temporary variable `t` to make sure `a` and `b` alias the same instance. `a = b = "something"` is just shorthand for multiple assignments, it doesn't do anything special like irrevocably make both `a` and `b` always alias the same instance. So when you do `b = "somethingelse"`, you change what instance `b` aliases, but `a` still refers to the same instance it referred to after the first assignment.

Comment: @cozycoding: The important point I want to get across is that variables don't contain the instances, so assignments don't copy instances like they would in C++ or some other languages. Variables merely contain a reference that allows you to find the instance. So when you do an assignment you change that reference. A lot of times it looks like the variable contains the instance, but this is an illusion. An abstraction. And if you are not aware of it, it can bite you when you have 2 variables referencing the same instance and change one variable only to find that the other has changed a swell.

Comment: @DSM: I found a repro for a similar issue, see [Shove failing because of pretty basic ld vs. optimize issue in stuf.util](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248577/shove-failing-because-of-pretty-basic-ld-vs-optimize-issue-in-stuf-util)