# Shove failing because of pretty basic ld vs. optimize issue in stuf.util

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I ran against another issue with shove (see [Shove knowing about an object but unable to retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224538/shove-knowing-about-an-object-but-unable-to-retrieve-it) ), but this time I've got a pretty simple repro showing why the dump/load doesn't work.

Looking at the def in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\shove-0.5.0-py2.7.egg\shove\base.py` for loads/dumps, it refers to ld,optimize in stuf.utils.

How come the below does not work?

```
>>> from stuf.utils import ld,optimize; d=[{'A':1},{'A':1}]; ld(optimize(d))
[{'A': 1}, {'A': 1}]
>>> from stuf.utils import ld,optimize; d=[{'AA':1},{'A':1}]; ld(optimize(d))
[{'AA': 1}, {'A': 1}]
>>> from stuf.utils import ld,optimize; d=[{'AA':1},{'AA':1}]; ld(optimize(d))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from stuf.utils import ld,optimize; d=[{'AA':1},{'AA':1}]; ld(optimize(d))
BadPickleGet: 3
>>>
```

Thx so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the versions of shove and stuf that are installed with, for example, pip, are not compatible.  I was able to download source from github and build both stuf and shove quickly on both OSX and Linux with 2.7.

```
git clone https://github.com/kwarterthieves/shove.git
git clone https://github.com/kwarterthieves/stuf.git
```

Resulted in these version numbers being installed:

```
stuf-0.8.13-py2.7.egg
shove-0.3.4-py2.7.egg
```

where pip installs:

```
shove-0.5.3-py2.7.egg-info
stuf-0.9.3-py2.7.egg-info
```

so I downgraded, but everything seems to be working okay now.

Comment: PyPi packages was updated today, just "pip install shove --upgrade" and you should be golden.